# Connecting to Camunda

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, zeebe

Am not able to connect to Camunda Cloud via nodejs

12:04:22.537 | zeebe |  INFO: Error connecting to Camunda Cloud.
12:04:22.656 | zeebe |  ERROR: [topology]: Attempt 7 (max: -1).
12:04:22.661 | zeebe |  ERROR: [topology]: 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the environment variables documented here: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/apis-clients/cli-client/ are set correctly.

```
export ZEEBE_ADDRESS='[Zeebe API]'
export ZEEBE_CLIENT_ID='[Client ID]'
export ZEEBE_CLIENT_SECRET='[Client Secret]'
export ZEEBE_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_URL='[OAuth API]'
```

https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/setup-client-connection-credentials/
should you how to create and download these.

Since the DNS resolution fails, you may have gotten the ZEEBE_ADDRESS wrong.

Comment: Ive followed this link https://docs.camunda.io/docs/0.26/guides/setting-up-development-project/

getting this error:  10:32:58.378 | zeebe |  INFO: Authenticating client with Camunda Cloud...
10:32:58.456 | zeebe |  ERROR: [topology]: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses


const zbc = new ZBClient({
 camundaCloud: {
   clientId: 'H--',
   clientSecret: '',
   clusterId: ''
 }
  })

This also give same error

Comment: Answer remains unchanged. Make sure you use the latest version, also of the doc.